# Integrating a probability current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, probability

I am trying to understand how to integrate the probability current in order to get the probability of the particle moving through a certain point. I have a particle moving in a potential which is made up of equally spaced wells. The formula I am given is the following : [image]
I am unsure of the format of the integral that I am supposed to use in order to get the correct probability. i.e. what bounds do I use after integrating the formula for j ?

Please let me know if anything is not clear so I can add more information.

Comment: Doesn't the problem literally tell you to integrate the probability current from $t=0$ to $t=4$?

Comment: @Puk but if I do that where would the point of x=L/2 come in to the calculation ?

Comment: The probability current can be a different function of time at each point in space. You need to use the one at $x=L/2$ if you need to find how much the total probability in the region $x > L/2$ changes in the given time range.